How to make the Windows Hello dialog appear in the foreground with passkeys?
I regularly need to log into a website which requires 2FA and for which I have enabled a passkey with Windows Hello using fingerprint or face recognition. However, whenever I use it, the Windows Security dialog shows up in the background. I then have to use the taskbar to select it before I am able to authenticate.
How can I make this dialog open in the foreground?

I use Firefox most of the time, but I observe the same behavior with Chrome or Edge.
I am using Windows 11 23H2 build 22631.4169. I have admin rights on the machine.
I have noticed other people having similar issues with Bitwarden and Windows Terminal without a proper solution (the latter contains links to old Windows 10 updates but I assume they are not relevant to me).

If you use a password manager like 1Password which supports Passkeys does that resolve the problem?

@Ramhound I’d like to use the native feature of the browser if that’s possible… But I installed Bitwarden and I also see Windows Hello appear in the taskbar before it gets brought to the foreground. I assume it’s the mitigation they mention in the ticket I linked.

As a workaround/solution for this issue, I’m now using Hellofy developed by GitHub user @ados8, who had commented about it on the Bitwarden issue I linked in the question.
After reviewing their code, I rebuilt the .exe myself with AutoIt so that I don’t need to worry about an untrusted executable found online.
